# Clients for connecting to Redshift on Mac M1

Tags: amazon-web-services, arm, amazon-redshift, apple-m1, sql-workbench-j

I'm really struggling to get SQLWorkbench/J Build 128 working on my 2021 M1 MacBook. Java8 JRE setup pages send me in loops, even referencing downloads for ARM dmgs that don't actually exist on the page that is linked to. Has anyone else had this struggle?

What other options do you guys use to connect to Redshift?

**Update: DBeaver is working really seamlessly if anyone else is having this problem! Drivers already installed. **